# Flutter Hive: Open and return Box in isolate

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-hive

I'm trying to open the box separately because the box contains so much data that it's causing my main UI to stutter/freeze. Is there a way to open the box separately and return the box object?

I asked ChatGPT and it gave this answer:

```dart
Future<Box> openBoxInIsolate(String boxName, String path) async {
  final receivePort = ReceivePort();
  await Isolate.spawn(
    _openBoxInIsolate,
    IsolateArgument(boxName: boxName, path: path, sendPort: receivePort.sendPort),
  );
  return await receivePort.first as Box;
}

void _openBoxInIsolate(IsolateArgument arguments) async {
  final box = await Hive.openBox(arguments.boxName, path: arguments.path);
  arguments.sendPort.send(box);
}

class IsolateArgument {
  final String boxName;
  final String path;
  final SendPort sendPort;

  IsolateArgument({required this.boxName, required this.path, required this.sendPort});
}
```

But this code gives an error:

> `Invalid argument(s): Illegal argument in isolate message: (object extends NativeWrapper - Library:'dart:io' Class: _RandomAccessFileOpsImpl@13069316)`

at `arguments.sendPort.send(box);` line.

Answer (score 0):

use this before open box

```
Hive.init(arguments.path);
```

Comment: Although this code might answer the question, I recommend that you also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.